# Java: Save an image to a file directory without exiting application

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm new to StackOverflow and Java so I apologize if this isn't in the right place and if my understanding of Java concepts is off. I have looked around online, but haven't found a solution to my problem, nor do I understand why this is happening.

I am making an application that takes a screenshot of my screen and saves it to the working source directory of the project. After it saves the image, another window opens up and displays that image.

My problem is saving the image. I can save it, however the screenshot does not appear in the project directory until after I close the entire program, thus causing an error as the image can not be read the first time around since the image doesn't exist in the file directory despite it being saved. After closing it, the image shows up in the directory and the program runs as it should with no errors after running it a second time.

I don't understand why this is happening. How come the image doesn't appear in the file directory until after the program is terminated and how would I go about solving this issue? I'm using **JavaFx** with **FXML** in **Inteliji Idea**.

Any help would be very appreciated.

```
// This method / function runs on a simple button press.
public void screenshot() throws Exception{


    // Hides the window
    boarderPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();

    String format = "jpg";
    String fileName = "FullScreenshot." + format;

            try {

                // This gives the window enough time to hide so it doesn't get caught in the screenshot
                Thread.sleep(500);


                Robot robot = new Robot();


                Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

                BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
                ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File("src\\image\\" + fileName));

                System.out.println("A full screenshot saved!");

            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }


    // Creates a new window that will display the screenshot
    Stage imageStage = new Stage();

    Parent newWindow = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("screenshotWindow.fxml"));
    imageStage.setTitle("Caliber --- Current Screen Shot Window");
    imageStage.setScene(new Scene(newWindow, 800, 800));
    imageStage.show();

    // Saves the screenshot location so it can be used in the other window
    MasterVariables.image = new Image("image\\" +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of your application as something that will be run on a **real** user's workstation.

A real user (i.e., not you) won't have any IntelliJ project. He/she won't have any `src` directory. All he/she will have is a read-only jar file containing the compiled classes and static resources of your application, a home directory, and a temporary directory.

So, save the image as a file, somewhere in the user's home directory or as a temporary file, and load it from that file, using **file IO** (and not the ClassLoader, which only has access to the resources in your read-only jar file). Or avoid saving it to a file in the first place, and just store it in memory.

If you want to know the reason why it doesn't work, it's because you're loading the image using the ClassLoader. The ClassLoader can load anything that is under a directory or a jar file that is in the classpath. Your src directory is not in the classpath.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I have it working now because of you.

Comment: Great. Glad to have helped. You should accept the answer, then. To thank me, but also tomark this question as answered.